# Using the function, how to disable and fetch the formgroupValues in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, formgroups

I need to disable the formControl and also want to fetch the data by using the function.

I used the following code for disabling the input text field

**(formControlNames:- numberPrefix,numberFormat,resetNumberFormat )**

```
onChanges() {
    this.soPreferenceFormGroup.get('numberPrefix').disable();
    this.soPreferenceFormGroup.get('numberFormat').disable();
    this.soPreferenceFormGroup.get('resetNumberFormat').disable();
 }
```

Following is the result which I got.Only numberMode is fetched.
[image]

Then when I used the **disabled** function directly in template method like below

```
<input pInputText type="text" formControlName="numberPrefix" class="form-control" placeholder="Required" disabled />
<input pInputText type="text" formControlName="numberFormat" class="form-control" placeholder="Required" disabled/>
<input pInputText type="text" formControlName="resetNumberFormat" class="form-control" placeholder="Required" disabled />
```

Now, the all formGroup values are fetched .Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Why value is not displaying while disabling using methods??

I want to disable and fetch the value using the function instead of writing directly in html template

Can anybody help me ??

Please verify this stackBlitz: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9drxhl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.value` returns all active properties of your form.

If you want the disabled values with it, use [`myForm.getRawValue()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue)

Comment: can u please  give me an example using stackblitz??

Comment: @AngelReji seriously ? That's a word to change ... But sure, as soon as you provide me with a [mcve] of your issue on stackblitz, I'd be happy to edit it.

Comment: Please verify this stackBlitz: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9drxhl).

Comment: @AngelReji [here you go ...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-giostg?file=src/app/app.component.html)